# Hibernate Spatial & OSGi

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, osgi, postgis, apache-karaf

I'm trying to use Hibernate-Spatial in an OSGi scenario and I'm having a really hard time getting this to work.

I'm using JBoss Fuse/Fabric8. So my stuff is running in Karaf (2.3.x) with container managed transactions.
The DB is PostgresDB (9.3) with the PostGIS running in Docker.




**Problem:**



My problem is retriving Geomety datatypes from the DB. I can persist the entities but i always get the following error when retrieving spatial data.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert object of type org.postgresql.util.PGobject
        at org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryValueExtractor.toJTS(PGGeometryValueExtractor.java:99)
```

**Context:**



Bundles loaded in the container:

```
hibernate-commons-annotations (4.0.4.Final)
hibernate-core (4.2.10.Final)
hibernate-entitymanager (4.2.10.Final)
hibernate-osgi (4.2.10.Final)
JTS Topology Suite (1.12)
Hibernate Spatial (4.0)
PostGIS JDBC driver (1.5.8)
PostgreSQL JDBC4 driver (9.1.902.jdbc4)
```

The entity:

```
...
      @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
      @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
      private Point location;
...
```

The datasource:

```
  <bean
    id="data_source_postgres" class="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource">
    <property name="serverName" value="serverName" />
    <property name="portNumber" value="portNumber" />
    <property name="databaseName" value="databaseName" />
    <property name="user" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
  </bean>

  <service ref="data_source_postgres" interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <service-properties>
      <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/postgresds" />
      <entry key="service.exported.interfaces" value="*" />
    </service-properties>
  </service>
```

The persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/postgresds)</jta-data-source>
    <class>entities.FooEntity</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>            
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

**Facts, conclusions and questions:**

1. When I run the code outside Karaf against the same DB, with the same dependencies but with a hand managed transaction, it works fine. 
   So it leaves me to conclude the problem is not incompatibility between any of the dependencies. If that was the case, it wouldn't work when running outside Karaf.
2. I've checked [*org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PGGeometryValueExtractor.toJTS*](https://github.com/maesenka/hibernate-core/blob/HS4.0/hibernate-spatial/src/main/java/org/hibernate/spatial/dialect/postgis/PGGeometryValueExtractor.java) implementation and conclude that the it is not supposed the retrieved object type to be a *PGobject* at all! In my case it should be a *org.postgis.Geometry.POINT*
3. reading similar post from other people I've thought the appropriate data types wouldn't be registered properly. But if that was the case, could it be persisting the Geometry with success and failing to retrieve it? How can I check which datatypes are in fact registered?
4. Whats the root of the problem? Is it the container managed transaction (Aires)? Are the bundles not exporting all its supposed to? Could it be the dependencies versions? Am i using the wrong dialect/driver/datasource?

Answer (score 1):

In OSGi when you encounter things that make absolutely no sense, its usually good to check for class loading issues.

Since the method is called with a totally unexpected type (you expected an object from postgis and received one from postgress) I could think that at some point a previous conversion has failed. I would check and see if there is a single package exported (or embedded) by multiple bundles which is a common source of such issues.

Comment: To add to this, OSGi usually prevents registering objects/factories/transformers simply by having each bundle in a different classloader; to me it looks like a bundle that does the conversion (possibly the Postgres driver) doesn't import org.postgis.Geometry; or the equivalent, postgis doesn't register that data type.

Comment: So, after reading iocanel and Tassos comments and rereading [Postgis Usage Notes](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/03-dialects/02-postgis/), which says "Beware of classpath problems in a J2EE container where the JDBC drivers live in a different classpath than the Postgis JDBC extensions and/or Hibernate Spatial.", I suppose the datatypes registered by postgis-jdbc are not available to hibernate when performing queries. I'll bundle Postgres-jdbc, Potgis-jdbc and Hibernate-Spatial all together and see if that makes a diference.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I've joined hibernate-spatial, postgres-jdbc and postgis-jdbc in the same bundle and the dam thing worked!

I'll commit the Bundle to https://github.com/albertocsm ASAP.

Comment: Don't think this is a good idea, rather should the postgres-jdbc have a optional import for postgis-jdbc and the hibernate-special should have those optional imports to. It's rather bad to wrap this up as one big blob. Though it's valid to have this as a first step to a clean environment and to find the bundles in  question.

Comment: Doesn't work with imports. Also tried having post*-jdbc bundles as hibernate-spatial's fragments. No success either. I suppose the bundle isolation mechanism doesn't align with the way postgis drivers are registered in their context (or vice versa).